# Python: Performing calculation on entire column if nth value in the column meets certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still a noob at Python so I apologize if the answer if obvious... I have some dataframes that look similar to this (simplified example):

```
      0     1     2     3     
0     2     1     1     1
1     3     2     2     2
2     4     3     3     3
3     2     4     4     0
```

Say I need to first check if the 4th row on every other column is larger than 1, and if they are, then subtract the entire column by 2. The result should look like this:

```
      0     1     2     3     
0     0     1     1     1
1     1     2     2     2
2     2     3     3     3
3     0     4     4     0
```

In this example the code should check if the 4th value (row3) in columns 0 and 2 are above 1, since since column 0 meets the requirement the entire column is subtracted by 2, and column 2 is ignored.

I currently have:

```
for flist in glob('*.csv'):
    print(flist)
    df = pd.read_csv(flist, delimiter = ',', header=None, index_col=False, skiprows=29, usecols=range(3,72))
    if df.loc[3,0::2] > 1:
        df.loc[:,0::2]-2
    if df.loc[3,0::2] < -1:
        df.loc[:,0::2]+2
```

There are probably other things wrong with this code but to start with, when I try to run it I get

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific in the condition for which column needs to be subtracted 2 from. Is it the first column that has a value in the 4th row greater than 1? Be very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform the check and the subtraction in a single line.

```
df.loc[:,((df.columns % 2 == 0) & (df.loc[3,:] > 1))] -= 2
```

Here `df.loc[:, condition]` filters the DataFrame by condition on the columns.
`condition` are in fact two conditions:

1. we want only every second column (`(df.columns % 2 == 0)`), 
   as well as (`&`)
2. only those columns where the entry in the fourth row is larger than 1 (`(df.loc[3,:] > 1))`)

From the thus filtered DataFrame you subtract 2 by using `-= 2`.

Note that the way we select only every second column works, because we haven't specified any header in the DataFrame. If there was a header, one could use e.g. `(numpy.arange(len(df.columns)) % 2 == 0)`.

Here is the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd

a =[[2 ,    1 ,    1 ,    1],
    [3 ,    2 ,    2 ,    2],
    [4 ,    3 ,    3 ,    3],
    [2 ,    4 ,    4 ,    0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)

df.loc[:,((df.columns % 2 == 0) & (df.loc[3,:] > 1))] -= 2
print df
#   0  1  2  3
#0  0  1 -1  1
#1  1  2  0  2
#2  2  3  1  3
#3  0  4  2  0
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression `df.loc[3,0::2]` gets you every alternate column in the list, and trying to get the truth value of a set of numbers is meaningless.

If you're trying to compare more than one value in the list, you should have to separate checks for it. Something like

```
if df.loc[3][0] > 1 and df.loc[3][2] > 1:
```

Also, I don't think you can increment an entire column in an expression, you'll need to do that by iterating through each element of the column

```
for I in range(0,5):
    df.loc[3][i]=df.loc[3][i]+1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a more efficient way to perform the check? The example I posted is a simplified version, my data sheet has about 80 columns, would I have to have 40 if statements for every other column?